# "Action not allowed (line 0)." error when running a script function from the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-geocoder

I have the following script:

```html
function GEOCODE(place) {
  try {
    var results = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(place).results;
    if(results.length > 0) {
      return [[results[0].geometry.location.lat, results[0].geometry.location.lng]]
    }
  }catch(e) {}
}

function test() {
  Logger.log(GEOCODE("Brown University"));
}
```

Which had worked in the past. Now I can run the test function from the script editor but when I use either function within the spreadsheet I get a "Action not allowed (line 0)." error. As far as I know the only thing that might have caused it to stop working is the deletion of the account that owned the document. I'm now trying to fix it from an account in a different GSuite org than the original owner and I only have edit permissions.